# CRS-4639: Could not contact Oracle High Availability Services

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, red-hat

tengo un gran pequeño detalle. Hace unos días intente parchar una BD con GI standalone oracle 19.3 a 19.18. El detalle es que marco el siguiente error:

```
2023/05/29 15:09:54 CLSRSC-2501: The AFD driver install actions failed.
```

Procedí a investigar detalladamente y al parecer el Kernel no es compatible con esos drivers. Al final, decidí reinstalar todo el software de base de datos y ahora el nuevo problema es que, después de que el parche fallo, el ASM no levanto correctamente, motivo por el cual no me deja desinstalar GRID HOME. Ya intente de todo un poco, basándome en los Doc de oracle, entre ellos, levantar el ASM manualmente, sin tener éxito. Me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

```
[root@hph7lp-cdysp bin]# ./crsctl start has
CRS-6706: Oracle Clusterware Release patch level ('3161362881') does not match Software patch level ('724960844'). Orot be started.
CRS-4000: Command Start failed, or completed with errors.
```

Y este es el error que me da al intentar desintalar GRID HOME:

```
[root@hph7lp-cdysp ~]# /grid/app/grid19c/crs/install/roothas.sh -force  -deconfig -paramfile "/tmp/deinstall2023-05-30_02-40-24PM/response/deinstall_OraGI19Home1.rsp"
Using configuration parameter file: /tmp/deinstall2023-05-30_02-40-24PM/response/deinstall_OraGI19Home1.rsp
The log of current session can be found at:
  /tmp/deinstall2023-05-30_02-40-24PM/logs/hadeconfig.log

PRCR-1070 : Failed to check if resource ora.asm is registered
CRS-5168 : unable to communicate with ohasd
2023/05/30 14:43:57 CLSRSC-180: An error occurred while executing the command '/grid/app/grid19c/bin/srvctl stop asm -force'

PRCR-1070 : Failed to check if resource ora.asm is registered
CRS-5168 : unable to communicate with ohasd
2023/05/30 14:43:57 CLSRSC-180: An error occurred while executing the command '/grid/app/grid19c/bin/srvctl remove as m -force'

PRCR-1070 : Failed to check if resource ora.ons is registered
CRS-5168 : unable to communicate with ohasd
2023/05/30 14:43:58 CLSRSC-180: An error occurred while executing the command '/grid/app/grid19c/bin/srvctl config on s'
CRS-4639: Could not contact Oracle High Availability Services
CRS-4000: Command Stop failed, or completed with errors.
The command '/grid/app/grid19c/perl/bin/perl -I/grid/app/grid19c/perl/lib -I/grid/app/grid19c/crs/install -I/grid/app/grid19c/xag /grid/app/grid19c/crs/install/roothas.pl -force -deconfig -paramfile /tmp/deinstall2023-05-30_02-40-24PM                     /response/deinstall_OraGI19Home1.rsp' execution failed
```